# Web scraping Google Images with Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I have been tasked with making an application that the user uses to search for three pictures of theirQuery . It could be written in any language, and Python was suggested. However, my GUI skills with Python suck, I am most familiar with Java, and I have downloaded the Eclipse SWT package, which I intend on using.

**OK, what have you done so far**

I pimped their example code that makes a simple web browser. I have it display Google Images as the home page, and intend on using JavaScript/jQuery to automate the filling in of theirQuery, and returning the first three pictures. (I also plan on somehow using JavaScript/jQuery to return the three pictures.)

According to the documentation for Eclipse SWT, `evaluate()`,`execute()` are used to evaluate,execute JavaScript: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html

Here is the code that I have used:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.LocationEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.LocationListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.ProgressEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.ProgressListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.StatusTextEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem;
public class BrowserCodeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
        gridLayout.numColumns = 3;
        shell.setLayout(gridLayout);
        ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar(shell, SWT.NONE);
        ToolItem itemBack = new ToolItem(toolbar, SWT.PUSH);
        itemBack.setText("Back");
        ToolItem itemForward = new ToolItem(toolbar, SWT.PUSH);
        itemForward.setText("Forward");
        ToolItem itemStop = new ToolItem(toolbar, SWT.PUSH);
        itemStop.setText("Stop");
        ToolItem itemRefresh = new ToolItem(toolbar, SWT.PUSH);
        itemRefresh.setText("Refresh");
        ToolItem itemGo = new ToolItem(toolbar, SWT.PUSH);
        itemGo.setText("Go");

        GridData data = new GridData();
        data.horizontalSpan = 3;
        toolbar.setLayoutData(data);

        Label labelAddress = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        labelAddress.setText("Address");

        final Text location = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        data = new GridData();
        data.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        data.horizontalSpan = 2;
        data.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        location.setLayoutData(data);

        final Browser browser;
        try {
            browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
        } catch (SWTError e) {
            System.out.println("Could not instantiate Browser: " + e.getMessage());
            display.dispose();
            return;
        }
        data = new GridData();
        data.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        data.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        data.horizontalSpan = 3;
        data.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        data.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
        browser.setLayoutData(data);

        final Label status = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        data.horizontalSpan = 2;
        status.setLayoutData(data);

        final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(shell, SWT.NONE);
        data = new GridData();
        data.horizontalAlignment = GridData.END;
        progressBar.setLayoutData(data);

        /* event handling */
        Listener listener = new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                ToolItem item = (ToolItem)event.widget;
                String string = item.getText();
                if (string.equals("Back")) browser.back(); 
                else if (string.equals("Forward")) browser.forward();
                else if (string.equals("Stop")) browser.stop();
                else if (string.equals("Refresh")) browser.refresh();
                else if (string.equals("Go")) browser.setUrl(location.getText());
           }
        };
        browser.addProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ProgressEvent event) {
                    if (event.total == 0) return;                            
                    int ratio = event.current * 100 / event.total;
                    progressBar.setSelection(ratio);
            }
            @Override
            public void completed(ProgressEvent event) {
                progressBar.setSelection(0);
            }
        });

        browser.addLocationListener(new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(LocationEvent event) {
                if (event.top) location.setText(event.location);
            }
            @Override
            public void changing(LocationEvent event) 
            {
                //System.out.println("Something is happening.");
            }

        });
        itemBack.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);
        itemForward.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);
        itemStop.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);
        itemRefresh.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);
        itemGo.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);
        location.addListener(SWT.DefaultSelection, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) 
            {
                browser.setUrl(location.getText());
                System.out.println("New URL loaded");
            }
        });

        shell.open();
        browser.setUrl(
            "https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi&ei=m8g4VLndMaz4igKlvoDADg&ved=0CAMQqi4oAQ");
        //browser.setVisible(false);
        boolean jQueryExecuted = browser.execute("$(\'#lst-ib\').val(\'snopes\')");
        if (!jQueryExecuted)
        {
            System.out.println("Your jQuery didn't execute.");
        }
        jQueryExecuted = browser.execute("$(\'[name=btnG]\').click()");
        if (!jQueryExecuted)
        {
            System.out.println("Your jQuery didn't execute.");
        }
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }

        display.dispose();

    }

}
```

I don't think the issue is the code itself, as I have tried to set the text field automatically and it failed, both in Java and in my browser; /* the name of the text field is "lst-ib" */

**What are you trying to web-scrape?**

I am trying to web scrape Google images: https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi&ei=m8g4VLndMaz4igKlvoDADg&ved=0CAMQqi4oAQ .

The text field is an input with name "lst-ib". The button is an input with name "btnG". The text field is within a div with id of "gs_lc0". (I see multiple other input elements in there, too, of the exact same size).

Comment: val(), for some reason, is returning undefined for the input field

Comment: Why is nobody responding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, wow. It has been 10 hours and nobody has so much as commented on here but me. It turns out that the problem is much bigger than I thought: Browser from Eclipse SWT cannot execute jQuery.

Luckily, I found the Google Image API, which is written in JavaScript, and is deprecated, but still works. Also, I found some simple source code on the page: https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide#hiworld

I changed the `newImg.src = "/image-search/v1/result.tbUrl;"` to `newImg.src = result.tbUrl;` so that the images would load. This changes everything.

---

**What is your new plan?**

I now plan on using this code from Java. I plan on changing the src to the src that is the Google Image API that the JavaScript code uses, and then invoking the code to get the first three images. This is how, apparently, you run JavaScript from Java: [How to run javascript in java programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320308/how-to-run-javascript-in-java-programming) . If only I can figure out how to change the src of the JavaScript engine that Java uses to this: https://www.google.com/jsapi

Comment: I might go as far as to write the code in HTML (building off the HTML I talked about here), having Java read the entire file into a String, set the Browser HTML to that String via `Browser.setText(theHTML);` and then, when the user clicks the button to look up the images, use `Browser.execute('userQuery');` to show the images...